# Is it possible to store code in an object that can be run from another object?

Tags: java

In Java,

```
class BlaBlaThirty extends Parent {
    void foo(String s, int i) {}
}

class BlaBlaTwentyNine extends Parent {
    void foo(int i, Bla a, This t, Other o) {}
}

class BlaBlaFive extends Parent {
    void foo(Bla a, Other o) {}
}

...
```

Many different classes all with a method foo().

```
ArrayList<Object> arr;
arr.add(blablai);
arr.add(blablaj);
arr.add(blablak);
...
```

array arr contains many objects which are instances of these classes.
The problem is that all these foo() methods do not have the same parameters. How to call these methods with the right parameters?

```
arr.get(i).foo(?,?,?);
```

my solution:

all foo method have one ArrayList params parameter which contains all the needed parameters as Object :

```
class BlaBlaX {
     void foo(ArrayList<Object> params) {}
}
```

then, I add the variables names of the variables needed in foo() in the class containing foo. before calling foo(), I call getFooParams() :

```
class BlaBlaTwentyTwo extends Parent {

    ArrayList<Object> getFooParams() {

        ArrayList<String> p;
        p.add("i");
        p.add("banana");
        p.add("volkswagen");

        return p;
    }

    void foo(ArrayList<Object> params) {
        Int i = (int) params.get(0);
        Fruit banana = (Fruit) params.get(1);
        Car volkswagen = (Car) params.get(2);
    }
}
```

object calling foo() methods contains all the variables required in foo() :

```
class ObjCallingFoo {
   int i;
   Fruit banana;
   car volkswagen;

   //see below for what is here to call foo()
}

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

p = arr.get(i).getFooParams();
int size = p.size();
ArrayList<Object> arrParams = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    String variableName = p.get(i);
    Field field = objCallingFoo.getClass.getField(variableName);
    arrParams.add(field);
}
```

I can now call foo with the right parameters :

```
arr.get(i).foo(arrParams);
```

I haven't tested yet.
What do you think of that?

Is it possible to store code in an object that can be run from another object?

OR

How to call a method with parameters of another object if we don't know what are the specific member variables to pass as parameters to the method in calling object?

Comment: Well, since they all inherit from the same base class (parent), then that means that they have similar functionalities. That doesn't mean that you should have them all in the same ArrayList. Every problem in programming, can be solved with another layer of abstraction. My opinion is that you should change this structure.

Answer (score 1):

You need an abstraction that includes the specific method to call **and** how to call it. This is what the *Strategy* and *Command* design patterns can do.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use `instanceof`:

```
Object parent = obj.get(i);

if(parent instanceof BlaBlaThirty)
    ((BlaBlaThirty)parent).foo(?,?);
else if(parent instanceof BlaBlaTwentyNine)
    ((BlaBlaTwentyNine)parent).foo(?,?,?);
else if(parent instanceof BlaBlaFive )
    ((BlaBlaFive )parent).foo(?,?);
```

**P.S.** This is not good to hold all these objects in one list. Your code organization should be refactored indeed!

Comment: your solution supposes hundreds of if instanceof else if instanceof else if instaceof ... if ArrayList<Object> obj contains hundreds of objects. I'm going to think about refactoring if possible.

Comment: This is yours! Actually, I would remove your code completely and rewrite it correctly.

Comment: How to stock objects if it's not in an array? It's a game, when the player plays a card of type Card, for example CardPikahu extends Card, CardCharizar extends Card, I add a card in ArrayList<Card> cardsInHand doing cardsInHand.add(cardPikachu); cardsInHand representing all cards in player's hand. All cards have common method like attack() but attack()'s parameters can vary from card to card. No idea how to refactor.

Answer (score 0):

You could have different constructors and a basic method foo() in Parent. 
Then you can override it in every class und do something different with the fields.
But i think it is an option but maybe you should refactor your code/abstraction/inheritance in another way.

```
class Parent {
   void foo(){}
}

class BlaBlaThirty extends Parent {
//Contructor with String s, int i

void foo() {
   //Do something here with fields  String s, int i
}

class BlaBlaTwentyNine extends Parent {
//Contructor with int i, Bla a, This t, Other o

void foo() {
  //Do something here with fields int i, Bla a, This t, Other o
}

class BlaBlaFive extends Parent {
//Constructor Bla a, Other o
void foo() {
  //Do something here with fields Bla a, Other o
}
```

...

Many different classes all with a method foo().

```
ArrayList<Parent> parent;
parent.add(blablai);
parent.add(blablaj);
parent.add(blablak);
...

parent.foo()
parent.foo()
parent.foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a interface:

```
public interface Blainterface{
   public void foo();
}

public class BlaBlaTwentyNine extends Parent implements Blainterface {
     public void foo() {}
}
....
ArrayList<Blainterface> obj;
obj.add(blablai);
obj.add(blablaj);
obj.add(blablak);

//now you can acces it like 

obj.get(2).foo();
```

It gets even better. You may have a class that doesn't implement the interface but with a method that looks the same:

```
public interface Blainterface{
    public void foo();
}

public class Blubclass{
    public void bar(){ //note its bar here and not foo()!!!
      //do something cool!  
    }
}
//...

ArrayList<Blainterface> obj;
obj.add(blablai);
obj.add(blablaj);
obj.add(blablak);
Blubclass blub = new Blubclass(); //note that blub has no foo() method.
obj.add(blub::bar);

//And that call will work too:
obj.get(3).foo(); //this will call bar() in the Blubclass.
```

now one step further with someting that has different parameters:

```
public interface Blainterface{
    public void foo();
}

public class Bazclass{
    public void baz(Sting name){ //note its baz here and not foo() and it has a parameter!!!
      //do something cool!  
    }
}
//...

ArrayList<Blainterface> obj;
obj.add(blablai);
obj.add(blablaj);
obj.add(blablak);
Bazclass baz = new Bazclass(); //note that baz has no foo() method and a parameter.
obj.add(()->baz.baz("name"));//mapping of parameters

//And that call will work too:
obj.get(3).foo(); //this will call baz("name") in the Bazclass. Even though we use a different method name and parameters for the call.
```

Only thing you need is to define the signature you want to use, when you call the methods, in an interface. 
And you have to tell java how to map the parameters(it cant't guess).

Answer (score 0):

Finally what I may do,

```
class FooParamsNeeded {
    public boolean blaBlaI;
    public boolean blaBlaJ;
    public boolean i;
    public boolean blaBlaK;
    public boolean banana;
    public boolean blaBlaL;
    public boolean volkswagen;
    public boolean blaBlaM;
    ...
}
```

//------------ in object where foo() is, there is a specic getFooParams() method with parameters needed set to true----------

```
FooParamsNeeded getFooParams() {
    FooParamsNeeded fpn = new FooParamsNeeded();
    fpn.i = true;
    fpn.banana = true;
    fpn.volkswagen = true;
    return fpn;
}
```

//--------------------

```
class FooParams {
    public BlaBlaI blaBlaI;
    public BlaBlaJ blaBlaJ;
    public int i;
    public BlaBlaK blaBlaK;
    public Fruit banana;
    public BlaBlaL blaBlaL;
    public Car volkswagen;
    public BlaBlaM blaBlaM;
    ...
}
```

//-------in object where other object's foo() method is called-----

```
FooParams setFooParams(FooParamsNeeded fpn) {
    FooParams fp = new FooParams();
    if (fpn.blaBlaI)
        fp.blaBlaI = blaBlaI;
    if (fpn.blaBlaJ)
        fp.blaBlaJ = blaBlaJ;
    if (fpn.i)
        fp.i = i;
    if (fpn.blaBlaK)
        fp.blaBlaK = blaBlaK;
    if (fpn.banana)
        fp.banana = banana;
    if (fpn.blaBlaL)
        fp.blaBlaL = blaBlaL;
    if (fpn.volkswagen)
        fp.volkswagen = volkswagen;
    if (fpn.blaBlaM)
        fp.blaBlaM = blaBlaM;
    ...

    return fp;
}

FooParamsNeeded fpn = arr.get(i).getFooParams();
FooParams fp = setFooParams(fpn);
arr.get(i).foo(fp);
```

//-------------------------------------

I think I should have 10-15 possible different paramaters and so 10-15 if statements in setFooParams().

Comment: if the parameters are of the same type (meaning: you can you use an array) you could also use a variable parameterlist like : void foo(String ... params){}

Comment: And then again replacing  a bunch "instanceof" if's with the same amount of "if's" with your self created typespecification won't make the huge difference. But for the latter case  enum might be an option.